# perl: sysread on an in-memory file handle?

Tags: perl

This, unfortunately, doesn't work:

```
my $input = "this is a test";
open(my $fh, "<", \$input);
my $n = sysread($fh, $buf, 4);  # want $n == 4, $buf eq 'this'
```

Replacing `sysread` with `read` works as expected.

Is this expected? Could it be made to work? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After sysread, does the variable $! contain "Bad file descriptor"? Then you may have encountered bug 72428 "sysread does not work on a filehandle to a scalar" ( https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=72428 )

Answer (score 1):

This works, however, I'm not quite sure why or if you really want to be doing this.

```
my $input = "this is a test";
open(my $fh,'-|',"echo $a");  # open a pipe instead and echo the string
my $n = sysread($fh,$buf,4) or warn $!;
```

Note that a failed sysread sets `$!` so you can check for errors.

Comment: I encountered this in testing where I was using a file handle to a scalar because I didn't want to go through the trouble of creating a real file. In general it would be nice if this worked since then, as the above RT ticket says, pass the file handle to any module which uses `sysread`.

Comment: If you want to simulate an input file, you can use the `__DATA__` construct with `while(<DATA>)`

Comment: You should check `sysread($fh, $buf, $count) == $count`, **not** whether the return was `undef`. Pretty sure `sysread` isn't going to go back and make up the difference for you on a short read, and that that's therefore your own problem to handle.

Comment: This is a very nice workaround. But there is a shell command line size limit (128K on my system), so it can't be used in this form for large or arbitrary sized data.